# Using a RandNum class to choose a Word from a Words Class, which is implemented by a word class

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm trying to create a Java program. It is a fill in the blank word game.

I have a random number generator that is used to get the index and length of a word from an array of 25 words.

I 10 classes, but I'm only concerned with three of them at the moment.

-I have a Selection class (this calls the random number generator and chooses the word)

-There is a Word class. This was provided for us and I did not write it. I'm assuming this gets and sets the word.

-There is a Words which stores the array of words (I have not made them yet, but it will be an array of 25).

My confusion is on how Word will utilize Words, which in turn utilizes the Selection class.

```
public class Word {

    Selection word = new Selection();

    String name;

    public Word() {
        super();
        name = new String("");
    }

    public Word(String w) {
        super();

        name = new String(w);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setWord(String s){
        this.name = new String(s);
    }
}

public class Words {
    public Word wordList[];

    public Words() {
        super();

        wordList = new Word[24];

        for (int i=0; i<24; i++) {
            wordList[i] = new Word();
        }
    }
}

public class Selection {

    public String word;
    int a;
    int b;

    //Number of blank spaces. These will change as difficulty progresses
    int blank;
    int blank2;
    //

    //words class
    Words newWord = new Words();

    RandNum  rand = new RandNum(a,b);
    RandNum lengthOfWord = new RandNum(1,20);
    RandNum indexOfWord = new RandNum(0,24);
    RandNum blanksInWord = new RandNum (blank, blank2)
}
```

I would love to know if my using the RandNumGen in the Selection is the right call.

I feel like I'm close, but I'm second guessing myself a little. We were kind of thrown in the deep end and dared to swim, so I'm trying to cram as much as I can while still finishing the assignment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If there are 25 words, you should make the array of length 25, not 24.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where the RandNum class is, I know that JAVA has the Random class which when creating a new Random(), then calling Random.nextDouble() it returns a value between 0 and 1, this value can be multiplied by 24 and cast to int to get a random number b/w 0-24.

Comment: We were given a random number generator. It randomly generates two numbers to create a range for the strings.

Comment: The random number generator is fine then, I would change the array definition to be wordList = new Word[25]; not exactly sure where else you are stuck.

Comment: I dont know how to use it. I've created a selection class. I'm thinking the selection class would use the RandNumGen to get the word out of Words, then set it in Word? Am I on the right track?

Comment: It does not look like you should be creating a new Words object in selection because this is where all of the words will be stored, and that should only happen once.  So you probably want a static variable of type Words, and the Selection class would choose the random number, and from there it would return words[randNum]

Comment: public String select(){
    
    return word[indexOfWord];
   }

Comment: Something like that?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Awesome. I still have a week to do this, so I will bash my head against it some more. Thanks for the help, Sir!

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to use what I typed, yet I'm getting an errorr: Type Mismatch. Cannot convert randnum to int

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to use the rand num function nextRandomIntegerInRange(). I'm trying to use return word[indexOfWord.nextRandomIntegerInRange()]

Comment: What is the primitive type inside of the RandNum class?

Comment: Actually, I think I've found another way to do this.